# Adding a count of values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there another way I can sum up counts with less code?

I'm using a view (my only option) to try to find out if a customer spent money during any two of the last 5 calendar years

Table name:
    V_PERSON
    V_REVENUE

Columns:
    V_PERSON.ID

```
V.REVENUE.PersonID
V.REVENUE.Year1 revenue for the year (currently 2016)
V.REVENUE.Year2 revenue for the year (currently, 2015)
V.REVENUE.Year3
V.REVENUE.Year4
V.REVENUE.Year5
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT V_PERSON.ID

FROM V_PERSON

WHERE 
(

(
SELECT '1'
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID  
AND V_REVENUE.Year1 > 0
)

+

(
SELECT '1'
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID  
AND V_REVENUE.Year2 > 0
)

+

(
SELECT '1'
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID  
AND V_REVENUE.Year3 > 0
)

+

(
SELECT '1'
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID  
AND V_REVENUE.Year4 > 0
)

+

(
SELECT '1'
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID  
AND V_REVENUE.Year5 > 0
)

) >= 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using `exists` with multiple `case` statements:

```
select id
from person p 
where exists (
    select 1
    from revenue r 
    where p.id = r.personid
        and case when r.year1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when r.year2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when r.year3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when r.year4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
            case when r.year5 > 0 then 1 else 0 end >= 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT V_PERSON.ID
FROM V_PERSON
WHERE 
(
SELECT  (case when V_REVENUE.Year1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +  
    (case when V_REVENUE.Year2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when V_REVENUE.Year3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when V_REVENUE.Year4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) +
    (case when V_REVENUE.Year5 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM V_REVENUE
WHERE V_REVENUE.PersonID = V_PERSON.ID) >= 2
```

Comment: I like this one too.  Thanks.